# Mostrar productos asociados en el Index de la vista. YII2

Tags: php

Tengo un inconveniente que no he podido solucionar, necesito que los productos asociados de mi código se muestren en el index, es decir se muestren por cada cliente que productos llevó, así como lo hice en el View, en el View se muestra como debe ser: pedido1 con todos los datos y datos del cliente y los productos que llevo que son los productos asociados. En el index, se muestra todos los pedidos y toda la información del cliente y el pedido pero no muestra los productos es lo que quiero hacer.

En la vista:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use kartik\grid\GridView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Pedidos */

//$this->title = $model->Id;
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Pedidos'), 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="pedidos-view">
<h3 class="panel-title"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i>LISTAR PEDIDO</h3>
<p><p><p><?//=  Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Crear', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success'])?></p></p></p>
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'estado.Nombre',
            'Id',
            'RemitoNro',
            'Fecha', 
            'encabezados.Cliente', 
            'cliente.DNI',
            'cliente.fullTodo',
            'cliente.Direccion',
            'cliente.fullTels',
            'apodo',
            'encabezados.DetallesVenta', 
            'canalventa.Nombre',
            'medipago.Nombre',
            'Idcompra',
            'IdPago',
            'Valorenvio',
            'TotalPedido',
            'TotalProducto2',
            'encabezados.Otros', 
            'Observaciones',
            'encabezados.DetallesEntrega', 
            'agencia.Nombre',
            'FechaEntrega',
            'Lugarentrega',
            'encabezados.Vendedores', 
            'vendedores.fullTodov',

            ],

    ]) ?>

    <hr>
    <h1>Productos asociados al pedido</h1>

    <?php
        Pjax::begin();

        echo GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'columns' => [
                ['class' => '\kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],

                [
                    'attribute' => 'producto_id',
                    'format' => 'raw',
                    'value' => 'producto.ProductosNombre',
                    'enableSorting' => false,
                ],
                [
                    'attribute' => 'cantidad',
                    'format' => 'raw',
                    'contentOptions' => ['style'=>'text-align: right;'],
                    'enableSorting' => false,
                ],
                [
                    'attribute' => 'valor_unitario',
                    'format' => 'raw',
                    'contentOptions' => ['style'=>'text-align: right;'],
                    'enableSorting' => false,
                ],
                [
                    'attribute' => 'valor_total',
                    'format' => 'raw',
                    'contentOptions' => ['style'=>'text-align: right;'],
                    'enableSorting' => false,
                ],
                [
                    'attribute' => 'fecha_registro',
                    'format' => 'raw',
                    'contentOptions' => ['style'=>'text-align: center;'],
                    'enableSorting' => false,
                    'value' => function($model)
                    {
                        return date('Y-m-d h:i a', strtotime($model->fecha_registro));
                    }
                ]
            ],
        ]);

        Pjax::end();
    ?>

</div>
```

En el index:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\grid\GridView;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
//use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
//use kartik\select2\Select2;
use kartik\datecontrol\DateControl;
use kartik\date\DatePicker;
use kartik\select2\Select2;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\models\Estadosp;
use app\models\Agencias;
use app\models\Mediopago;
use app\models\Canales;
use app\models\Pagosp;
use app\models\Vendedores;
use kartik\editable\Editable;
use yii\helpers\Json;
use app\models\PedidoProducto;


/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel app\models\PedidosSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

//$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Pedidos');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="pedidos-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        //'options' => [ 'style' => 'table-layout:fixed;' ],
        'rowOptions' => function ($model) {

              /*if ($model->EstadoId == 1) {
                  return ['style' => 'background-color: #99FF33'];
              }*/
              if ($model->EstadoId == 1) {
                  return ['class' => 'info'];
              }
              if ($model->EstadoId == 2) {
                  return ['style' => 'background-color: #CCFF66' ];
              }
              if ($model->EstadoId == 3) {
                  return ['style' => 'background-color: #FFFF66' ];
              }
              if ($model->EstadoId == 4) {
                  return ['class' => 'danger'];
              }
          },
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'floatHeader'=>true,
        'perfectScrollbar' => true,
        'resizableColumns'=>false,
        'hover'=>true,
        'showPageSummary' => true,
        'summary'=>'Mostrar todo / Exportar',



        'panel' => [
        'heading'=>'<h3 class="panel-title"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i>TRANSACCIONES PEDIDO</h3>',
        'type'=>'success',
        'before'=>Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Crear', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']),
        'after'=>Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i> Resetear Grid', ['index'], ['class' => 'btn btn-info']),
        'footer'=>true
        ],

        'columns' => [
            [
              'class' => '\kartik\grid\SerialColumn',
            ],
            ['class' => '\kartik\grid\ActionColumn'],

            [
              'class'=>'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
              'attribute'=>'EstadoId',
              'editableOptions'=>[
                  'header'=>'Estado',
                  'asPopover' => true,

                  'format' => \kartik\editable\Editable::FORMAT_BUTTON,

                  'inputType'=>\kartik\editable\Editable::INPUT_DROPDOWN_LIST,

                  'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Estadosp::find()->all(), 'Id','Nombre'),
                  'options' => ['class'=>'form-control', 'prompt'=>'Seleccione estado'],

                  ],

               'value' => function($searchModel){
                return $searchModel->EstadoId;
                }, 
                'value' => 'estado.Nombre',  
                'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(Estadosp::find()->joinWith('pedidos')->orderBy('Id')->all(), 'Nombre', 'Nombre'),

                'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
                'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Estadosp::find()->orderBy('Id')->asArray()->all(), 'Nombre', 'Nombre'), 
                'filterWidgetOptions' => [
                'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
                  ],
                'filterInputOptions' => ['placeholder' => 'Filtrar...'],
               'format' => 'raw'
            ],

            [
              'class'=>'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
              'attribute'=>'Idcompra',
              'editableOptions'=>[
                  'header'=>'Factura',
                  'asPopover' => true,
                  'format' => \kartik\editable\Editable::FORMAT_BUTTON,
                  'inputType' => \kartik\editable\Editable::INPUT_TEXT,
                  ],
                'width' => '500px',
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'PagoId',
                'value' => 'pagosped.Nombre',
                'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(Pagosp::find()->joinWith('pedidos')->orderBy('Id')->all(), 'Nombre', 'Nombre'),
            ],
            'IdPago',
            [
                'attribute' => 'AgenciaId',
                'value' => 'agenciacombo.Nombre',
                'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
                'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Agencias::find()->orderBy('Id')->asArray()->all(), 'Nombre', 'Nombre'), 
                'filterWidgetOptions' => [
                'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
                  ],
                'filterInputOptions' => ['placeholder' => 'Filtrar...'],
               'format' => 'raw'
            ],


            [
                'attribute' => 'FechaEntrega',
                'value' => 'FechaEntrega',
                'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_DATE,

                'filterWidgetOptions' =>([              
                'pluginOptions'=>[ 

                    'format'=>'yyyy-m-d',
                    'opens'=>'bottom',
                    'autoclose' => true,
                ]
                 ])

            ],

            'Lugarentrega',
             [
              'class'=>'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
              'attribute'=>'RemitoNro',
              'editableOptions'=>[
                  'header'=>'RemitoNro',
                  'asPopover' => true,
                  'format' => \kartik\editable\Editable::FORMAT_BUTTON,
                  'inputType' => \kartik\editable\Editable::INPUT_TEXT,
                  ],
                'width' => '500px',
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'ClienteId',
                'value' => 'cliente.DNI',
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => '                   ',
                'value' => 'cliente.fullTodo',
            ],

            'Fecha',
            'Id',
            'apodo',

            [
                'attribute' => 'VendedoresId',
                'value' => 'vendedores.DNI',
            ],


            [
                'attribute' => '',
                'value' => 'vendedores.fullTodov',
            ],

            [
                'attribute' => 'CanalventaId',
                'value' => 'canalventa.Nombre',
               // 'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'max-width: 800px;'],
                //'contentOptions'=>['width' => '200px'],
                //'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(Agencias::find()->joinWith('pedidos')->orderBy('Id')->all(), 'Nombre', 'Nombre'),
                'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
                'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Canales::find()->orderBy('Id')->asArray()->all(), 'Nombre', 'Nombre'), 
                'filterWidgetOptions' => [
                'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
                  ],
                'filterInputOptions' => ['placeholder' => 'Filtrar...'],
               'format' => 'raw'

            ],  
            [
                'attribute' => 'MedipagoId',
                'value' => 'medipago.Nombre',
               // 'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'max-width: 800px;'],
                //'contentOptions'=>['width' => '200px'],
                //'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(Agencias::find()->joinWith('pedidos')->orderBy('Id')->all(), 'Nombre', 'Nombre'),
                'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
                'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Mediopago::find()->orderBy('Id')->asArray()->all(), 'Nombre', 'Nombre'), 
                'filterWidgetOptions' => [
                'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
                  ],
                'filterInputOptions' => ['placeholder' => 'Filtrar...'],
               'format' => 'raw'

            ],  
            'TotalProducto',
            'TotalProducto2',
            'Valorenvio',
            'TotalPedido',
            'Observaciones',
        ],
    ]); ?>
    <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
</div>
```

En el controlador:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use app\models\PedidoProducto;
use Yii;
use app\models\Pedidos;
use app\models\PedidosSearch;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\base\ModelEvent;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

//use app\models\Modelo;
use yii\web\Response;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

/**
 * PedidosController implements the CRUD actions for Pedidos model.
 */
class PedidosController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Pedidos models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new PedidosSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Pedidos model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $modelo = $this->findModel($id);
        $searchModel = new PedidoProducto();
        $searchModel->pedido_id = $modelo->Id;
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->searchProductos(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $modelo->Id);

        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $modelo,
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Pedidos model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Pedidos;
        $productos = [new PedidoProducto];

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $productos = Pedidos::createMultiple(PedidoProducto::classname());
            Model::loadMultiple($productos, Yii::$app->request->post());

            // ajax validation
            /*if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
                Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
                return ActiveForm::validateMultiple($productos);
            }*/

            $valido = $model->validate();
            $valido = Model::validateMultiple($productos) && $valido;

            if ($valido) {
                $transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
                try {
                    $totalProducto = 0;
                    if($model->save())
                    {
                        foreach ($productos as $k=>$producto)
                        {
                            $mPro = $producto->producto;

                            //Calcular total producto
                            $valorProducto = ($producto->cantidad * $mPro->ProductosPrecioVenta);
                            $totalProducto = ($totalProducto + $valorProducto);

                            $producto->pedido_id = $model->Id;
                            $producto->valor_unitario = $mPro->ProductosPrecioVenta;
                            $producto->valor_total = $valorProducto;
                            $producto->fecha_registro = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                            $producto->save();

                            //Actualizar el stock del producto
                            //Productos::actualizarStockProducto($model->ProductosId);
                            $mPro->actualizarStockProducto();
                        }
                    }

                    if($model->Id <> '')
                    {
                        //Calcular total pedido;
                        $totalPedido = ($totalProducto + $model->Valorenvio);

                        //Actualizar total producto y total pedido
                        $model->TotalProducto = $totalProducto;
                        $model->TotalPedido = $totalPedido;
                        $model->save();

                        $transaction->commit();
                        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->Id]);
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $transaction->rollBack();
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'productos' => (empty($productos)) ? [new PedidoProducto] : $productos,
        ]);
    }

    public function actionCreate_old()
    {
        $model = new Pedidos();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $producto = $model->productos;

            //Calcular total producto
            $totalProducto = $model->Cantidad * $producto->ProductosPrecioVenta;

            //Calcular total pedido;
            $totalPedido = $totalProducto + $model->Valorenvio;

            $model->TotalProducto = $totalProducto;
            $model->TotalPedido = $totalPedido;
            $model->save();

            //Actualizar el stock del producto
            //Productos::actualizarStockProducto($model->ProductosId);
            $producto->actualizarStockProducto();
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->Id]);
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'productos' => false,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Pedidos model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $productos = $model->pedidoProductos;

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $oldIDs = ArrayHelper::map($productos, 'id', 'id');
            $productos = Pedidos::createMultiple(PedidoProducto::classname(), $productos);
            Model::loadMultiple($productos, Yii::$app->request->post());
            $deletedIDs = array_diff($oldIDs, array_filter(ArrayHelper::map($productos, 'id', 'id')));

            // ajax validation
            /*if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
                Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
                return ActiveForm::validateMultiple($productos);
            }*/

            $valido = $model->validate();
            $valido = Model::validateMultiple($productos) && $valido;

            if ($valido) {
                $transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
                try {
                    if($model->save())
                    {
                        if (! empty($deletedIDs)) {
                            PedidoProducto::deleteAll(['id' => $deletedIDs]);
                        }

                        $totalProducto = 0;
                        foreach ($productos as $k=>$producto)
                        {
                            $mPro = $producto->producto;

                            //Calcular total producto
                            $valorProducto = ($producto->cantidad * $mPro->ProductosPrecioVenta);
                            $totalProducto = ($totalProducto + $valorProducto);

                            $producto->pedido_id = $model->Id;
                            $producto->valor_unitario = $mPro->ProductosPrecioVenta;
                            $producto->valor_total = $valorProducto;
                            if($producto->id == '')
                            {
                                $producto->fecha_registro = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                            }
                            $producto->save();

                            //Actualizar el stock del producto
                            //Productos::actualizarStockProducto($model->ProductosId);
                            $mPro->actualizarStockProducto();
                        }

                        //Calcular total pedido;
                        $totalPedido = ($totalProducto + $model->Valorenvio);

                        //Actualizar total producto y total pedido
                        $model->TotalProducto = $totalProducto;
                        $model->TotalPedido = $totalPedido;
                        $model->save();
                    }

                    if($model->Id <> '')
                    {
                        $transaction->commit();
                        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->Id]);
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $transaction->rollBack();
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
            'productos' => (empty($productos)) ? [new PedidoProducto] : $productos,
        ]);
    }

    public function actionUpdate_old($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $producto = $model->productos;

            //Calcular total producto
            $totalProducto = $model->Cantidad * $producto->ProductosPrecioVenta;

            //Calcular total pedido;
            $totalPedido = $totalProducto + $model->Valorenvio;

            $model->TotalProducto = $totalProducto;
            $model->TotalPedido = $totalPedido;
            $model->save();

            //Actualizar el stock del producto
            //Productos::actualizarStockProducto($model->ProductosId);
            $producto->actualizarStockProducto();
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->Id]);
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
            'productos' => false,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Pedidos model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $productos = $model->pedidoProductos;
        if($productos)
        {
            foreach($productos as $pr)
            {
                $producto = $pr->producto;
                $pr->delete();
                $producto->actualizarStockProducto();
            }

        }
        $model->delete();




        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Pedidos model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Pedidos the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Pedidos::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException(Yii::t('app', 'The requested page does not exist.'));
    }
}
```

Imagen de lo que necesito hacer (Solo lo de la columna: Productos asociados, lo que se vé en la imagen de productos asociados es hecho con editor no lo está mostrando, es así como quiero que se vea y que muestre ademas del nombre de producto como está la cantidad y el valor de cada producto. Lo que me falta es solo eso en el index):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Observese que en el view, se ve todos los datos incluídos los de los productos, pero no me sirve porque es a nivel de 1 solo pedido, y yo quiero que se vea esa misma informacion en el index a nivel de todos los registros, para usar las opciones de filtrado y exportación que ofrece el index.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el modelo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No cupo mas caracteres, entonces anexo archivo con contenido del modelo: 
[ver modelo](http://www.hospitaldesanjose.gov.co/web/modelopedidoproducto.txt)

La opción row options no me afecta lo del grid de productos asociados. 
[image: Problema row options]

Error de exportación:
Así sale:
[image: Como sale al exportar luego de cambios]

Como debería salir: [image: Así debe salir]

Comment: Estás hablando de agregar datos a dos GridView totalmente diferentes, podrías poner una imagen de como esperas que sea tu resultado?

Comment: Sr1871, buen día, ya subí la imagen de lo que quiero realizar. solo me falta eso, lo hice con un editor para que tenga una idea mas clara de lo que quiero. Muchas gracias

Comment: he editado la respuesta ya con lo el modelo en el gridView incrustado, por favor no uses imágenes, pega el código, es más fácil de manejar

Comment: Gracias por responder, incrusté la imagen debido a que no me dejó pegar más codigo por superar los 30000 caracteres. Sin embargo acabo de anexar un link con el archivo en formato .txt.

Comment: Ok, pero igual como te había mencionado,lo que puse de respuesta ya es la respuesta, pruébala y si te marca algún error pones el error y vemos en que falla

Comment: Sale esto: Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException Getting unknown property: app\models\Pedidos::id

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente tienes que insertar el gridview como columna del gridview

En tu gridview del index, inserta el gridview del view y pon el formato como html,quedaría así

```
    GridView::widget([
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
  //'options' => [ 'style' => 'table-layout:fixed;' ],
  'rowOptions' => function ($model) {

    /*if ($model->EstadoId == 1) {
        return ['style' => 'background-color: #99FF33'];
    }*/
    if ($model->EstadoId == 1) {
        return ['class' => 'info'];
    }
    if ($model->EstadoId == 2) {
        return ['style' => 'background-color: #CCFF66' ];
    }
    if ($model->EstadoId == 3) {
        return ['style' => 'background-color: #FFFF66' ];
    }
    if ($model->EstadoId == 4) {
        return ['class' => 'danger'];
    }
  },
  'filterModel' => $searchModel,
  'floatHeader'=>true,
  'perfectScrollbar' => true,
  'resizableColumns'=>false,
  'hover'=>true,
  'showPageSummary' => true,
  'summary'=>'Mostrar todo / Exportar',

  'panel' => [
    'heading'=>'<h3 class="panel-title"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i>TRANSACCIONES PEDIDO</h3>',
    'type'=>'success',
    'before'=>Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Crear', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']),
    'after'=>Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i> Resetear Grid', ['index'], ['class' => 'btn btn-info']),
    'footer'=>true
  ],

  'columns' => [
      [
        'class' => '\kartik\grid\SerialColumn',
      ],
      ['class' => '\kartik\grid\ActionColumn'],

      [
        'class'=>'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
        'attribute'=>'EstadoId',
        'editableOptions'=>[
            'header'=>'Estado',
            'asPopover' => true,

            'format' => \kartik\editable\Editable::FORMAT_BUTTON,

            'inputType'=>\kartik\editable\Editable::INPUT_DROPDOWN_LIST,

            'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Estadosp::find()->all(), 'Id','Nombre'),
            'options' => ['class'=>'form-control', 'prompt'=>'Seleccione estado'],

            ],

         'value' => function($searchModel){
          return $searchModel->EstadoId;
          }, 
          'value' => 'estado.Nombre',  
          'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(Estadosp::find()->joinWith('pedidos')->orderBy('Id')->all(), 'Nombre', 'Nombre'),

          'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
          'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Estadosp::find()->orderBy('Id')->asArray()->all(), 'Nombre', 'Nombre'), 
          'filterWidgetOptions' => [
          'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
            ],
          'filterInputOptions' => ['placeholder' => 'Filtrar...'],
         'format' => 'raw'
      ],

      [
        'class'=>'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
        'attribute'=>'Idcompra',
        'editableOptions'=>[
            'header'=>'Factura',
            'asPopover' => true,
            'format' => \kartik\editable\Editable::FORMAT_BUTTON,
            'inputType' => \kartik\editable\Editable::INPUT_TEXT,
            ],
          'width' => '500px',
      ],
      [
          'attribute' => 'PagoId',
          'value' => 'pagosped.Nombre',
          'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(Pagosp::find()->joinWith('pedidos')->orderBy('Id')->all(), 'Nombre', 'Nombre'),
      ],
      'IdPago',
      [
          'attribute' => 'AgenciaId',
          'value' => 'agenciacombo.Nombre',
          'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
          'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Agencias::find()->orderBy('Id')->asArray()->all(), 'Nombre', 'Nombre'), 
          'filterWidgetOptions' => [
          'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
            ],
          'filterInputOptions' => ['placeholder' => 'Filtrar...'],
         'format' => 'raw'
      ],


      [
          'attribute' => 'FechaEntrega',
          'value' => 'FechaEntrega',
          'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_DATE,

          'filterWidgetOptions' =>([              
          'pluginOptions'=>[ 

              'format'=>'yyyy-m-d',
              'opens'=>'bottom',
              'autoclose' => true,
          ]
           ])

      ],

      'Lugarentrega',
       [
        'class'=>'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
        'attribute'=>'RemitoNro',
        'editableOptions'=>[
            'header'=>'RemitoNro',
            'asPopover' => true,
            'format' => \kartik\editable\Editable::FORMAT_BUTTON,
            'inputType' => \kartik\editable\Editable::INPUT_TEXT,
            ],
          'width' => '500px',
      ],
      [
          'attribute' => 'ClienteId',
          'value' => 'cliente.DNI',
      ],
      [
          'attribute' => '                   ',
          'value' => 'cliente.fullTodo',
      ],

      'Fecha',
      'Id',
      'apodo',

      [
          'attribute' => 'VendedoresId',
          'value' => 'vendedores.DNI',
      ],


      [
          'attribute' => '',
          'value' => 'vendedores.fullTodov',
      ],

      [
          'attribute' => 'CanalventaId',
          'value' => 'canalventa.Nombre',
         // 'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'max-width: 800px;'],
          //'contentOptions'=>['width' => '200px'],
          //'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(Agencias::find()->joinWith('pedidos')->orderBy('Id')->all(), 'Nombre', 'Nombre'),
          'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
          'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Canales::find()->orderBy('Id')->asArray()->all(), 'Nombre', 'Nombre'), 
          'filterWidgetOptions' => [
          'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
            ],
          'filterInputOptions' => ['placeholder' => 'Filtrar...'],
         'format' => 'raw'

      ],  
      [
          'attribute' => 'MedipagoId',
          'value' => 'medipago.Nombre',
         // 'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'max-width: 800px;'],
          //'contentOptions'=>['width' => '200px'],
          //'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(Agencias::find()->joinWith('pedidos')->orderBy('Id')->all(), 'Nombre', 'Nombre'),
          'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
          'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Mediopago::find()->orderBy('Id')->asArray()->all(), 'Nombre', 'Nombre'), 
          'filterWidgetOptions' => [
          'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
            ],
          'filterInputOptions' => ['placeholder' => 'Filtrar...'],
         'format' => 'raw'

      ],  
      'TotalProducto',
      'TotalProducto2',
      'Valorenvio',
      'TotalPedido',
      'Observaciones',
      [
        'value' => function($model) {
          return GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
              'query' => PedidoProducto::find()->where(['pedido_id' => $model->id]) //cambia el query por el que sea que sea tu query
            ]),
        'rowOptions' => function ($modelPedido) use ($model) {

          /*if ($model->EstadoId == 1) {
              return ['style' => 'background-color: #99FF33'];
          }*/
          if ($model->EstadoId == 1) {
              return ['class' => 'info'];
          }
          if ($model->EstadoId == 2) {
              return ['style' => 'background-color: #CCFF66' ];
          }
          if ($model->EstadoId == 3) {
              return ['style' => 'background-color: #FFFF66' ];
          }
          if ($model->EstadoId == 4) {
              return ['class' => 'danger'];
          }
        },
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => '\kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],

            [
                'attribute' => 'producto_id',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value' => 'producto.ProductosNombre',
                'enableSorting' => false,
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'cantidad',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'contentOptions' => ['style'=>'text-align: right;'],
                'enableSorting' => false,
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'valor_unitario',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'contentOptions' => ['style'=>'text-align: right;'],
                'enableSorting' => false,
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'valor_total',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'contentOptions' => ['style'=>'text-align: right;'],
                'enableSorting' => false,
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'fecha_registro',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'contentOptions' => ['style'=>'text-align: center;'],
                'enableSorting' => false,
                'value' => function($model)
                {
                    return date('Y-m-d h:i a', strtotime($model->fecha_registro));
                }
            ]
        ],
          ]);
        },
        'format' => 'html'
      ]
  ],
]);
```

Lo único que tendrías que cambiar sería el query de tu dataProvider que desconzco dado que en tu controller lo pasas por searchParams y aquí ya no podrías hacerlo así, cambia eso y debería funcionar

Comment: Sr1871, Anexé el modelo de la parte de donde toma los datos para productos, y así pueda comprender un poco mejor el codigo. Muchas gracias

Comment: Esto no va en la edición de la respuesta, ya que se confunde, edita tu respuesta y ahí pégalo de nuevo para poder editar el query

Comment: Sale esto: Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
Getting unknown property: app\models\Pedidos::id

Comment: En qué linea te está saliendo?

Comment: Ahora me da problema la opción RowOptions, anexo detalles en la pregunta.

Comment: Solamente tienes que agregar el rowOptiosns el el gridview anidado dado que son gridViews distintos, edité la respuesta y puse como va

Comment: Ya le agregue la opción de RowOptions como en el grid principal, me sale que no está el campo EstadoId, y es cierto, ese campo esta en el modelo pedidos y el otro grid está usando el modelo PedidoProducto y en este no está. No sé como  seguir validando ese mismo campo del grid principal pero desde el grid secundario y de otro modelo. Gracias

Comment: Tienes razón. lo he editado, con ese cambio debería fucionar

Comment: Ahora funciona, pero los encabezados del segundo grid siguen de color por defecto. También acabó de darme cuenta que la exportación no está exportando como debe ser. Está repitiendo de nuevo todos los encabezados del primer grid luego de productos. Todo lo que sale luego de productos en la primera imagen ya está antes de medio de pago. Anexé en la pregunta las imágenes como sale y como debe quedar nótese la diferencia.

Comment: Lo que tu quieres hacer requiere código mucho más extenso para el export, dado que en el export no puedes incrustar tablas en tablas, para lo que quieres hacer te serviría crear tu mismo la tabla en lugar de usar el gridview y entonces debes empezar de nuevo

Comment: Buen día, cuando dice "empezar de nuevo", se refiere a que debo volver a hacer todo el código de la transacción es decir volver a crear tablas, modelos, vistas y controladores? o específicamente a que se refiere? Gracias

Comment: A que eso de exportar tablas anidadas no lo vas a poder hacer con GridView es más complicado, lo mejor sería hacerlo más nativo con html y php para que puedas manejas celdas y filas a tu antojo

Comment: Es decir no utilizo yii2 para esto sino que añado otra pagina con el código?